# Python: Changing date format using regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to change the date format in a text file so that it can be comma-delimited by Year, Month, and Day. Currently, it is in YYYY-MM-DD format and I am trying to replace the hyphens with commas without affecting the other hyphenated text in the file:

```
2011-1-1,59,44,29,55,42,26,93,80,66,30.15,30.05,29.96,10,8,4,14,3,22,T,7,Rain,201,39.2,76.7,KBWI
2011-1-26,35,34,32,34,31,25,100,82,64,30.04,29.79,29.54,9,2,0,22,11,29,1.82,8,Fog-Rain-Snow-Thunderstorm,23,39.2,76.7,KBWI #I dont want to remove the hyphens for the weather events
```

A friend told me to use regex with this expression:

```
re.findall('[\d]{4}-[\d]{1,2}-[\d]{1,2}')
```

It does find the patterns for all the dates formatted with hyphens, but I have no clue as to how to replace the hyphens with commas for all the lines in the textfile with this match. I'm thinking about creating a new text file with the edited data so that I can use it in another application. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using regexp is simple:

```
in = open("inputfile", "r")
out = open("outputfile", "w")

for line in in:
    line = line.split(",", 1)
    line[0] = line[0].replace("-", ",")
    out.write(','.join(line))

in.close()
out.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This one helped out alot. At this point in this course, we're doing string manipulation and I couldn't figure a way to join the rest of the string with the edited parts.

Answer (score 2):

Using [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html#module-fileinput) is a convenient way to alter files "in-place":

```
import fileinput
import re
import sys

for line in fileinput.input(filename,inplace=True):
    sys.stdout.write(re.sub(r'(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})',r'\1,\2,\3',line))
```

[re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) was used to replace the hyphens with commas. The first regex pattern matches only the dates, leaving the other hyphens in the lines untouched. The second argument `r'\1,\2,\3'` tells `re.sub` to replace the matched text with the first matched group `\d{4}`, followed by a comma, then the second matched group, `\d{1,2}`, followed by another comma, followed by the third matched group, `\d{1,2}`.

Comment: I'll try this method out as well for a future project I have to do involving input and output. I'm unsure of what to do involving regular expressions and whatnot. Beginner at Python.

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets aren't necessary around the `\d` entries.

Try using [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) with group numbers for the replace operation:

```
>>> d = '2011-1-1,59,44,29,55,42,26,93,80,66,30.15,30'
>>> re.sub(r'(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})', r'\1,\2,\3', d)
'2011,1,1,59,44,29,55,42,26,93,80,66,30.15,30'
```